# regex match words without two underscores next to each other

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that matches all words that contains alphanumeric characters + underscore, but not those that have two underscores next to each other. Actually I want to select words matching below regex but not containing "__"

regex : `[A-Za-z](\w){3,}[A-Za-z0-9]`

match example: `123dfgkjdflg4_aaa`, `ad`, `12354`

not match example: `1246asd__`

Comment: Why are python and django tagged?

Comment: Do you 'have to' do it in a regular expression? just check for '__' not being in the string

Comment: @MJafarMash Want to add it to this regex "[A-Za-z](\w){3,}[A-Za-z0-9]"

Comment: @MJafarMash means I want to match words with above regex but not having "__" in them.

Comment: @mohammad check if they match your regular expression, if they did check for double underscores not being present in the string

Comment: @MJafarMash I wanted to know if possible in one regex match.

Comment: It is definitely possible (mathematically proven :D) but may not worth the time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b[a-z0-9A-Z]*__\w*\b|(\b[A-Za-z0-9]\w*[A-Za-z0-9]\b)
```

And use the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/72hSXZ/3).

---

In `Python` this could be

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\b[a-z0-9A-Z]*__\w*\b|(\b[A-Za-z0-9]\w*[A-Za-z0-9]\b)')

words = ['a__a', '123dfgkjdflg4_', 'ad', '12354', '1246asd__', 'test__test', 'test']

nwords = [match.group(1) 
            for word in words 
            for match in [rx.search(word)]
            if match and match.group(1) is not None]

print(nwords)
# ['ad', '12354', 'test']
```

Or within a string:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\b[a-z0-9A-Z]*__\w*\b|(\b[A-Za-z0-9]\w*[A-Za-z0-9]\b)')

string = "a__a 123dfgkjdflg4_ ad 12354 1246asd__ test__test test"

nwords = filter(None, rx.findall(string))
print(nwords)
# ['ad', '12354', 'test']
```

---

Note that you can do all of this without a regular expression (probably faster and with less headaches):

```
words = ['a__a', '123dfgkjdflg4_', 'ad', '12354', '1246asd__', 'test__test', 'test']

nwords = [word 
            for word in words
            if "__" not in word and not (word.startswith('_') or word.endswith('_'))]
print(nwords)
# ['ad', '12354', 'test']
```

Comment: I don't want to match words like \_abc or abc\_

Comment: @mohammad: You need to be more precise in your problem description then!

Comment: @mohammad: Updated, now it should work, see the demo.

Comment: @mohammad: Additionally, you did have a match with `_` in the end in your question.

Comment: @mohammad: No worries. Have updated the answer and showed a non-regex ways as well.